# Как обратиться к значению элемента массива?

Tags: delphi

Есть массив: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как обратиться к значению элемента массива и записать в Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(...)

Comment: 'Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(aXYizu[8][0], aXYizu[8][1]);' - Нет?

Comment: Такая запись добавит одну точку на график(если она правильная). Я в delphi новичок и сейчас пробую и ищу как обращаются к элементу массива. Такой вариант обращения к значению массива, я попробую в первую очередь)

Comment: Series[0].AddXY(x1, y1); я думаю этот метод сразу добавляет значение по X и Y

Comment: aXYizu[8,1], такой вариант обращения к элементу массива, тоже может быть. Сейчас буду пробовать)

Comment: Ну так и есть... вы обращаетесь к 2-х мерному массиву...(точно не знаю, но думаю либо так) `x1 = aXYizu[8][0];  y1 = aXYizu[8][1]);`, либо `x1 = aXYizu[8,0];  y1 = aXYizu[8,1]);`  и  передаем в   `AddXY(x1,y1); `. _Выходит, варианты_ : 
 `Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(aXYizu[8][0], aXYizu[8][1]);` , либо `Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(aXYizu[8,0], aXYizu[8,1]);`